# Moving a View programmatically for api lower than 14

Tags: android, api, imageview, android-relativelayout, backwards-compatibility

I'm using the `getX`/`getY` and `setX`/`setY` methods to dynamically change the position of some `ImageView`s in order to make them follow the finger movements. The problem is that these methods require api level 14 and up. Is there any other way to make my cod compatiple with lower api levels?

Here is some code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        rel.removeView(finger[i]);
        finger[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.finger);
        try{
            finger[i].setX(e.getX(e.getPointerId(i))-100);
            finger[i].setY(e.getY(e.getPointerId(i))-100);
            rel.addView(finger[i]);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                rel.removeView(finger[i]);
            }
 }
```

`finger[i]` are my `ImageView`s and `rel`, the `RelativeLayout` of my xml.
`num` is the number of fingers currently touching the screen.

```
private ImageView[] finger = new ImageView[10];
private RelativeLayout rel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lower APIs you can try setting the margins of the `ImageViews`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = finger[i].getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin += i*100;
params.topMargin += i*100;
finger[i].setLayoutParams(params);
```